# Error with std::filesystem::copy copying a file to another pre-existing directory

Tags: c++, file, gcc, std, std-filesystem

See below for the following code, and below that, the error that follows.

```
std::string source = "C:\\Users\\cambarchian\\Documents\\tested";
std::string destination = "C:\\Users\\cambarchian\\Documents\\tester";
std::filesystem::path sourcepath = source;
std::filesystem::path destpath = destination;
std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing;
std::filesystem::copy(sourcepath, destpath);
```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
 what():  filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists [C:\Users\cambarchian\Documents\tested] [C:\Users\cambarchian\Documents\tester]
```

Tried to use filesystem::copy, along with trying different paths. No luck with anything. Not too much I can write here as the problem is listed above, could be a simple formatting issue. That being said, it worked on my home computer using visual studio 2022, however using VS Code with gcc 11.2 gives me this issue.

Comment: The expression `std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing;` has no effect, and a reasonable compiler would warn you about this. You need the other overload of `copy`.

Comment: i think you meant to call `copy(sourcepath, destpath, options)`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: I put the copy_options within the copy function but it didn't work so I started moving it around, I probably should have mentioned that. Still doesn't work when I write std::filesystem::copy(sourcepath, destpath, std::filesystem::copy_options::recursive);

Comment: `recursive`? Don't you want `std::filesystem::copy(sourcepath, destpath, std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);`  ?

Comment: please be careful with details. The code you posted has the same issue also on your home computer.

Comment: is the issue perhaps combining `recursive` and `update_existing` ?

Comment: It worked without even specifying any copy_options on my home computer, which I guess is why I'm not paying too much care with what I assign to it. Trying recursive and update_existing yields the same issue.

Comment: Moving non-working things around arbitrarily, hoping to stumble on to something that works, is one of the least effective methods for solving a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The overloads of [`std::filesystem::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) are documented. You're using the first overload, but want the second:

1. `void copy(from, to)` which is equivalent to [overload 2, below] using `copy_options::none`
2. `void copy(from, to, options)`

Writing the statement `std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing;` before calling copy doesn't achieve anything at all, whereas passing the option to the correct overload like

```
std::filesystem::copy(sourcepath, destpath,
                      std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);
```

should do what you want.

> ... it worked on my home computer using visual studio 2022 ...

you don't say whether the destination file existed in that case, which is the *first* thing you should check.

> I put the copy_options within the copy function but it didn't work so I started moving it around, I probably should have mentioned that.

Randomly permuting your code isn't a good way of generating clean examples for others to help with.

In the rare event that hacking away at something *does* fix it, I strongly recommend pausing to figure out *why*. When you've hacked away at something and it still doesn't work, by all means leave comments to remind yourself what you tried, but the code itself should still be in a good state.

> Still doesn't work when I write `std::filesystem::copy(sourcepath, destpath, std::filesystem::copy_options::recursive)`

Well, that's a different option, isn't it? Were you randomly permuting which `copy_options` you selected as well?

> Trying recursive and update_existing yields the same issue.

The documentation says

> The behavior is undefined if there is more than one option in any of the copy_options option group present in `options` (even in the `copy_file` group).

so you shouldn't be setting both anyway. There's no benefit to recursively copying a single file, but there *may* be a benefit to updating or overwriting one. If the destination already exists. Which, according to your error, it does.

Since you *do* have an error explicitly saying "File exists", you should certainly look at the "**options controlling `copy_file()` when the file already exists**" section of the table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options).

Answer (score 0):

Using:
**filesystem::copy_file(oldPath, newPath, filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);**

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2022 fixed the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).